# Can someone just make a post to register.php and register one billion accounts?

Tags: ajax, security, post

Is it possible to create a script that is executed outside of the server,
or with a browser add-on for example it automatically fills in form values, then submits the form all ready to be parsed by the server ? this way in three minutes a billion fake accounts could get registered very easily, imagine facebook which does not use any visible to the human captcha, a browser add on that performs the form submission and inserts the vals retrieved from a local database for new emails to be associated as that is a check - no duplicate emails, can thousands and thousands of fake accounts be created each day accross the globe?

What is the best method to prevent fake accounts? Even imagining the scenario of a rotating ips center with human beings registering just to choke the databases, achieving 30-50 million accounts in a year. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably better on the Security.Stackexchange.com website, but...

According to the [OWASP Guide to Authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication), CAPTCHAs are actually a bad thing.  Not only do they not work, induce additional headaches, but in come cases (per OWASP) they are illegal.

> **CAPTCHA**
>
> CAPTCHA (Completely automated Turing Tests To Tell Humans and Computers Apart) are illegal in any jurisdiction that prohibits
>   discrimination against disabled citizens. This is essentially the
>   entire world. Although CAPTCHAs seem useful, they are in fact, trivial
>   to break using any of the following methods:
>
> •  Optical Character Recognition. Most common CAPTCHAs are solvable using specialist
>   CAPTCHA breaking OCR software.
>
> •  Break a test, get free access to foo,> where foo is a desirable resource
>
> •  Pay someone to solve the CAPTCHAs.
>
> The current rate at the time of writing is $12 per 500 tests. 
>   Therefore implementing CAPTCHAs in your software is most likely to be
>   illegal in at least a few countries, and worse - completely
>   ineffective.

Other methods are commonly used.

- The most common, probably, is the e-mail verification process.  You sign up, they send you an email, and only when you confirm it is the account activated and accessible.
- There are also several [interesting alternatives](http://www.getelastic.com/6-captcha-alternatives-to-improve-conversion/) to CAPTCHA that perform the same function, but in a manner that's (arguably, in some cases) less difficult.
- More difficult may be to track form submissions from a single IP address, and block obvious attacks.   *But that can be spoofed and bypassed*.
- Another technique to use JavaScript to time the amount of time the user spent on the web page before submitting. Most bots will submit things almost instantly (if they even run the JavaScript at all), so checking that a second or 2 has elapsed since the page rendered can detect bots. *but bots can be crafted to fool this as well*
- The Honeypot technique can also help to detect such form submissions.  There's a nice example of implementation [here](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-7-Preventing-Automated-Form/ba-p/11778).

  - This page also talks about a Form Token method. The Form Token is one I'd never heard of until just now in this context.  It looks similar to an anti-csrf token in concept.

All told, your best defense, as with anything security related, is a layered approach, using more than one defense.  The idea is to make it more difficult than average, so that your attacker gives up ad tries a different site.  This won't block persistent attackers, but it will scale down on the drive-by attacks.

To answer your original question, it all depends on what preventative measures the website developer took to prevent people from automatic account creation.

Any competent developer would address this in the requirements gathering phase, and plan for it.  But there are plenty of websites out there coded by incompetent developers/teams, even among big-name companies that should know better.

Comment: There seem to be good ways to stop as you specified, drive-by attacks, specially the honey pot method, should keep some bots out, not those that check for the css values of the input and determine that as it is not visible, it shouldn't be touched (although I don't know myself how to determine the field is not visible if the style is applied through inheritance via an external css file), as for the form token, it would be generated also for the bot or script that is making the execution.

Comment: Link to "OWASP Guide to Authentication" is dead. *(This page has been deleted.)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is very easy to automate form submissions, for instance using [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). This is exactly why CAPTCHAs exist, to make it difficult to automate form submissions.

Verification e-mails are also helpful, although it'd be fairly straightforward to automate opening them and clicking on the verification links. They do provide protection if you're vigilant about blocking spammy e-mail domains (e.g. hotmail.com).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using simple scripts, which may or may not use browser extension (for example scripts written in Perl or shell scripts using wget/curl).

Most websites rely on tracking the number of requests received from a particular browser/IP before they enable CAPTCHA.

This information can be tracked on the server side with a finite expiry time, or in case of clients using multiple IPs (for example users on DHCP connection), this information can be tracked using cookies.